# Лучшая организация таблицы БД

Tags: php, mysql

Что лучше создать в таблице поле kolvo_comments (кол-во комментариев) или просто считать кол-во записей в таблице с комментариями? Чтобы нагрузка сильной не была. Наверное 1й вариант?

Comment: Лучшее — враг хорошего

Comment: ИМХО смешивать языки при именовании - моветон.

Что сложного в том, чтобы назвать поле comments_count вместо вашего kolvo_comments?

Comment: Это чтобы всем было понятно что это за поле. А потом решил всё-таки подписать в скобках. А вообще всегда стараюсь по англу всё называть, гугл переводчик в помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таблице с комментариями используйте:

```
SELECT COUNT(comments) FROM ...
```

Выведет количество строк в столбце. Если движок **InnoDB**, выборка будет быстрая и нагрузка на сервер, от скелетов, тоже не большая.

Если Вы создадите столбец с количеством (подсчетом) всех комментариев. Вам придется организовать либо автоматический пересчет, либо постоянно при добавлении комментария, выполнять дополнительное +1 в строку ***kolvo_comments***.
**INSERT**, **UPDATE**, а тем более автоматизация, больше напрягают сервер чем **SELECT**.

Comment: Спасибо, реализовал с помощью подсчёта записей)

Comment: > Если движок InnoDB, выборка будет быстрая и нагрузка на сервер, от скелетов, тоже не большая.

MyISAM быстрее будет (по EXPLAIN перед любым запросом можно судить о производительности), но он не поддерживает транзакции, а вообще, если приложение пишется без использования готовых решений и его не планируется переносить на любую другую БД, то лучше всю бизнес логику перенести в процедуры и функции БД. Правильно организовать базу (например, каскадное удаление записей) и добиться наилучшей оптимизации запросов - почти целая наука =)
Но такое решение гарантирует вам тонкие модель, контроллер.

Answer (score 1):

Что лучше зависит от того, какое отношение запись/чтение.
Если у вас что-то вроде обычного форума, то чтений в десятки и сотни раз больше, чем записи , а значит надо оптимизировать под чтение.

Лучшим решение в данном случае будет сделать поле comments_count и поддерживать его актуальность триггерами.

p.s. Не слушайте тех, кто говорит что MyISAM будет быстрее. MyISAM не кэширует данные, только индексы, и одним этим он уже проигрывает InnoDB, не говоря уже о десятке разных других причин.